# CSRF in Rails app that serves HTML and exposes an API for other clients such as iOS

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ios, ajax, api, csrf

The Ruby On Rails framework includes features that make it easy to build server applications that expose web service APIs. For example, a controller doing the following:

```
respond_to :html, :json, :xml

def show
  @thing = Thing.find(params[:id])
  respond_with @thing
end
```

...will handle 'show' actions for both web browsers, serving back HTML, and also render the item "@thing" as JSON or XML for requests that specify this data format.

In this particular example, the GET-based 'show' action doesn't involve any special security measures. Now consider a similar case to the above but for an action such as 'create' or 'update' - things activated by (simulated) PUT or (actual) POST requests. Now CSRF protection comes into play.

- http://guides.rubyonrails.org/security.html#cross-site-request-forgery-csrf

Here, sadly Rails only seems to be designed to cope with 'API calls' (for non-HTML format responses) from JavaScript code executing within a same-domain web page, for any controller that may serve HTML content to web browser clients, where CSRF protection is mandatory. JavaScript code can look for the magic 'meta' tag included by Rails, read the CSRF token and submit it back in XHR calls that invoke POST-based actions or similar on the server.

- http://weblog.rubyonrails.org/2011/2/8/csrf-protection-bypass-in-ruby-on-rails/

But what about external callers? What if we have Rails supporting a web site, but we want to make a native iOS or Android app that talks to the same head-end? That app would be making service calls - fine, Rails makes this easy - but any attempt to modify data on the server would fail because we don't have the CSRF token. **We can't just bypass CSRF protection** because the same controller code handles web browsers as well as "pure API" clients.

All answers related to CSRF issues with Rails and API calls seem to assume you'll have different controllers for such cases. But that's daft - what's the point of all the "make it easy to expose your app as a service" stuff if it's only of use to JavaScript code in your web page, unless you duplicate a bunch of code in special controllers that bypass CSRF just to allow non-web clients? Such extra controllers only increase the attack surface.

Does anyone know of a recommended "correct" pattern to deal with CSRF protection in Rails apps that have actions which may be 'called' by both web browsers, or non-web browser clients such as native iOS or Android apps? Built-in stuff like "respond_with(...)" doesn't do anything useful like always generated a JSON/XML object which included the CSRF token as an omnipresent field. The best I can think of is to do that myself, e.g. render "@thing" as:

```
{
  csrf: "abcdef...7890",
  object: { ...JSON representation of @thing... }
}
```

...but this seems like a bit of a hack, quite a lot of work and it seems to bypass CSRF for world+dog by announcing the most recent token on every request anyway. There *must* be a better way :-)

Answer (score 0):

Hmm, the [docs](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionController/RequestForgeryProtection/ClassMethods.html#method-i-protect_from_forgery) *say* that

> Turn on request forgery protection. Bear in mind that only non-GET, HTML/JavaScript requests are checked.

Suggesting that the requests for JSON and XML repsonses already won't be csrf checked, which is I think what your goal was? Does it not actually work like that though?

You could also over-ride [verify_authenticity_token](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionController/RequestForgeryProtection.html#method-i-verify_authenticity_token) in your controller to have custom logic for when to actually enforce the verifying; it's a pretty simple method calling out to other actual worker methods to do the verifiation and respond if not verified, so you could override to only do the verification check in certain circumstances if that's what you need. Or instead of overwriting, just write your own before_filter based on the same ideas, and call your own before filter -- looking at source, that's pretty much all `protect_from_forgery` does, add  `verify_authenticity_token` as a before_filter.  Doing either of these things may or may not be forward-compatible in the future though.

Ah, i see the [note you linked to](http://weblog.rubyonrails.org/2011/2/8/csrf-protection-bypass-in-ruby-on-rails/) announces CSRF protection happening for "*all* non-GET requests", so I guess that documentation saying it was only for HTML requests was out of date -- but that makes me think, what was the reason for that change? (That announcement doesn't document the nature of the vulnerability exactly, and I haven't gone hunting for the diffs). You can certainly succeed in un-doing it one way or another and making XML/JSON requests no longer checked for CSRF -- but will you be reintroducing whatever vulnerability 3.0.4 was meant to patch, will it matter for your app? I have no idea.

Comment: Yes, Rails changed to run the filter on *all* such requests and as is so often the case for Rails changes, it was pretty much "we did this, lump it". Gotta love the ivory tower! Anyway... Thanks, I'll have a look into filters. It might not be forwards compatible but Rails breaks its API all the time anyway. I seem to spend less time writing useful code, than I do patching up apps because Rails has changed its public, documented API in a way that breaks callers conforming cleanly to that API. I can certainly see why Rails suffers from so much abandonware ;)